# ORA-12545: Network Transport: Unable to resolve connect hostname

Tags: oracle, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-functions-runtime

Getting following exception two week once in PROD, when calling azure function from core api 3.1.

Below issue occurred when establishing the connection with oracle DB using ADO.Net. especially when executes the conn.open().

```
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(strSQLQuery, conn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.Text
            };
            OracleDataReader odr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Once restarted the app service from azure portal, it would be resolved.

Error - ora-12545 network transport unable to resolve connect hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below can be worked around.

1. If you are using the tnsname.ora,Please make sure its configured
   correctly. Check tnsname.ora file for prod and check for
   servername,See if the prod listener exists in listener.ora file, it
   must be missing.So try to add the listener for prod environment similar to dev
   ,if present.
2. If the Connection string had DNS name, try replacing it with IP
   address. Try to use user service name as they have different names for
   product and dev separately which can be useful  even if SID is same
   (in some cases).Always Ensure that the host field of the local_listener is
   properly set to a name which can be resolved by the Oracle client.

Or

3. Try to update host files to contain the requird server and host port.
   Go to
   \etc\hosts . Insert  server name and
   server IP in here and save.
4. Also check the .net version , it may be incompatible sometimes,
   maybe that’s why , after restarting ,its setting itself and the
   problem is resolved in azure app service.or Some times issue maybe
   due to firewall being restricting in azure portal.

You can raise a support request from overview page from troubleshoot blade ,if the issue still remains.

**Reference:**
[oracle - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332202/ora-12154-tnscould-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified-while-installin)

Comment: _"See if the prod listener exists in listener.ora file"_   No listener.ora file is required.  If there is no listener.ora, the listener process will quite happily start with all default values.  And for the majority of installations, this is all that is required for the listener.